# two random variable converge almost surely,does the product of this two random variables converge almost surely?

Tags: probability

I have a problem that

If $X_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}X$ and $Y_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}Y$,can we get that $X_nY_n\rightarrow_{a.s.}XY$?

I know that it is ture when converge in probability ,but I can't find a counterexample for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability, so it is true a fortiori. However, since the easiest way to prove it for convergence in probability is by using the fact that it holds for almost sure convergence, you may be interested in an independent proof.

Call $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, X_n(\omega)\not\to X(\omega)\}$ and $B=\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, Y_n(\omega)\not\to Y(\omega)\}$. Then $\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, X_n(\omega)Y_n(\omega)\not\to X(\omega)Y(\omega)\}\subseteq A\cup B$, which is a null set by hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Does it also hold when converge in $L_r$ or in distribution?

Comment: In $L^r$ yes, distribution no.