# $X_n\stackrel{a.s.}\rightarrow X, Y_n \stackrel{a.s.}{\rightarrow} Y \implies X_n Y_n \stackrel{a.s.}\rightarrow XY$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How to proof $X_n\rightarrow^{a.s} X, Y_n\rightarrow^{a.s} Y$, thus $X_n Y_n\rightarrow^{a.s} XY$
(2) The proof One:

I try to show  $P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X_nY_n-XY|>\epsilon)=0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$, then we can conclude that $X_n Y_n\rightarrow^{a.s} XY$

$P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X_nY_n-XY|>\epsilon)=P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X_nY_n-X_nY+X_nY-XY|>\epsilon)=P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X_n(Y_n-Y)+(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon)=P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)+X(Y_n-Y)+(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon)\leq P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P(|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P(|(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon/3)$

We need to show $P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$， that is $Y_n\rightarrow^{a.s} Y$ and $X$ is a random variable, we want to show $Y_n X\rightarrow^{a.s.} YX$

I use truncate to see this part $P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\leq P(|X|> M, \bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P(|X|\geq M, \bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3) \leq P(|X|> M, \bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|X(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)+P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty} |M(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3) \leq P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/(3M))+P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty} |M(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\rightarrow 0$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$

The similar to show, $P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|(X_n-X)Y|>\epsilon/3)\rightarrow 0$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$

As , we have  $P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)\leq P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|(X_n-X)|>\epsilon/3)+P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3)$ if n is large enough, we can bound $|Y_n-Y|$ and  |X_n-X| by $1$ .  Thus we also have $P(\bigcup_{n=m}^{+\infty}|(X_n-X)(Y_n-Y)|>\epsilon/3) \rightarrow 0$ as $m\rightarrow \infty$

Thus we prove the inequality.  I only know the definition of convergence in probability and almost surely. Can anyone give some suggestions, either for the proof based on the basic definition or other much simpler proof?

I am a self-learner. These questions are from Chung Kai-lai's book. Thanks a lot!

(2) The proof two:
The suggestion proof is very simple and clear.  It shows as below.
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n Y_n \not\to XY) \leq \mathbb{P}(\{X_n \not\to X\}\cup \{Y_n \not\to Y\}) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_n \not\to X) + \mathbb{P}(Y_n \not\to Y) = 0 + 0 = 0$$

Here the first inequality follows because if $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ and $Y_n(\omega) \to Y(\omega)$ for some $\omega $, then $X_n(\omega)Y_n(\omega) \to X(\omega) Y(\omega)$. By contraposition, we get

$$\{X_nY_n \not\to XY\} \subseteq \{X_n \not\to X\}\cup \{Y_n \not\to Y\}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932445/two-random-variable-converge-almost-surely-does-the-product-of-this-two-random-v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overcomplicate this.

$$\mathbb{P}(X_n Y_n \not\to XY) \leq \mathbb{P}(\{X_n \not\to X\}\cup \{Y_n \not\to Y\}) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_n \not\to X) + \mathbb{P}(Y_n \not\to Y) = 0 + 0 = 0$$

Here the first inequality follows because if $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ and $Y_n(\omega) \to Y(\omega)$ for some $\omega $, then $X_n(\omega)Y_n(\omega) \to X(\omega) Y(\omega)$. By contraposition, we get

$$\{X_nY_n \not\to XY\} \subseteq \{X_n \not\to X\}\cup \{Y_n \not\to Y\}$$

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your suggestion is very precious!

Comment: Very welcome! Good luck with measure theory/probability. These are very fun topics to study!

Comment: This answer also has the advantage that it works for general measures, while your approach only generalises to finite measure spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will try to apply if I meet the similar problem.

Comment: If this answers your question, you might consider accepting it so other users know your question has been answered :)

Comment: How to accept it? Do I need to update my answer or there is a system?  Many thanks!

Comment: There should be a sign left next to my answer you can click on. The "v" sign. It stands near the votes on this answer.

Comment: I will try it. Not so familiar with the system. Thanks for your nice suggestion!

Comment: Don't feel obligated though to accept an answer! Only do this when you think your question is sufficiently answered. If you still have doubts on something or if you are looking for another answer, please tell or edit your post to clarify. The following link may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Your suggestions are very helpful! I will do it later on if I have obtained some other helpful answers

Comment: Isn't the statement "if $X_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)$ and $Y_n(\omega) \rightarrow Y(\omega)$ then $X_n(\omega) Y_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega) Y(\omega)$" what we want to show?  So the first inequality is only valid if the statement is true.  This argument feels circular.

Comment: @Gauss What I do is show the inclusion $\{X_n Y_n \not\to XY\}\subseteq \{X_n \not\to X\}\cup \{Y_n\not \to Y\}$ by contraposition. What exactly is circular about this?

Comment: @QuantumSpace I believe the goal is to prove $X_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} X, Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}Y \implies X_n Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} XY$.  However, in your reasoning for why $\{X_nY_n \not \rightarrow XY\} \subseteq \{X_n \not \rightarrow X\} \cup \{Y_n \not \rightarrow Y\}$, it appears you are using the contrapositive of $A: X_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega), Y_n(\omega) \rightarrow Y(\omega) \implies X_n(\omega) Y_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)Y(\omega)$, which is the goal. So, it reads to me: if $A$ is true, then step 1 is true, and step 1 true means $A$ is true.

Comment: @Gauss I highly struggle to see what is the issue here. You do know that the limit of a product is the product of the limits? This is known from a basic calculus course...

Comment: @QuantumSpace, I thought the arrows in the answer were shorthand for a.s. convergence.  New notation for me.  In case others misread as I did, $X_n Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} XY$ requires by definition $\Pr[ \omega : X_n(\omega) Y_n(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)Y(\omega)] = 1$, which must be demonstrated given only $X_n  \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} X$ and $Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} Y$.