# $ X_n\stackrel{P}\rightarrow X\text{, }Y_n\stackrel{P}\rightarrow Y \Rightarrow X_nY_n\stackrel{P}\rightarrow XY $. How to show this?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, solution-verification

> Let $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ be two sequences of random variables such that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability and $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ in probability. Show that $X_n Y_n$ converges to $XY$ in probability.

Hence, we have to show that:
$$
X_n\stackrel{P}\rightarrow X\text{, }Y_n\stackrel{P}\rightarrow Y \Rightarrow X_nY_n\stackrel{P}\rightarrow XY
$$

I was thinking about some way to 'rewrite' $X_nY_n$. In particular,
$$X_nY_n=X_n(Y_n-X_n)+X_n^2$$
At this point, I was thinking that, for a sufficiently large $M\in\mathbb{N}$, for $n\geq M$, since $\lim(a\cdot b)=\lim(a)\cdot\lim(b)$ and $\lim(a+b)=\lim(a)+\lim(b)$, 
$$\lim\limits_{n}(X_nY_n)=\lim(X_n)\cdot\lim(Y_n)-\lim(X_n)\cdot\lim(X_n)+\lim(X_n^2)=$$ $$=\lim(X_n)\cdot\lim(Y_n)-\lim(X_n)\cdot\lim(X_n)+\lim(X_n)\lim(X_n)=$$ 
$$=X\cdot Y -X^2 +X^2=XY$$
However, I am pretty sure this is not the right way for the following reason:

*convergence in probability of $X_nY_n$ to $XY$ requires that $\lim\limits_{n}\mathbb{P}\left(|X_nY_n-XY|>\varepsilon\right)=0$ and I think that my reasoning - should it be correct - is not sufficient.*

**How could I proceed to solve such an exercise alternatively?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the following equivalence:

> $X_n \stackrel{\mathbb{P}} \to X$ if and only if every subsequence of
>   $(X_n)_n$ has a further subsequence that converges almost surely to
>   $X$.

Now, we show $X_n Y_n \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\to XY$. Let $(X_{n_k} Y_{n_k})_k$ be a subsequence of $(X_nY_n)_n$. Then $(X_{n_k})$ has a further subsequence $(X_{n_{k_l}})_l$ that converges almost surely to $X$ and $(Y_{n_{k_l}})_l$ has a further subsequence $(Y_{n_{k_{l_j}}})_j$ that converges almost surely to $Y$. Then since also $(X_{n_{k_{l_j}}})_j$ converges to $X$ almost surely, we can deduce that $X_{n_{k_{l_j}}}Y_{n_{k_{l_j}}} \to XY$ almost surely (refer to [$X_n\stackrel{a.s.}\rightarrow X, Y_n \stackrel{a.s.}{\rightarrow} Y \implies X_n Y_n \stackrel{a.s.}\rightarrow XY$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472838/x-n-stackrela-s-rightarrow-x-y-n-stackrela-s-rightarrow-y-implies-x?rq=1)).

We can conclude, because we have found a further subsequence of $(X_{n_k}Y_{n_k})_k$ that converges almost surely.

I have to admit that this looks ugly but the idea is simple.

Comment: Two questions: *first*: I have never heard before of the iff result you quoted. Could you please give me a reference?; *second*: I cannot understand why if, in general, $a_n\rightarrow a$ a.s. and $b_n\rightarrow b$ a.s., then $a_n b_n\rightarrow ab$ a.s. (it seems to me you have implicitly used such a result). Thank you a lot :) @ε-δ

Comment: Second question, see the link in my answer. I'm looking for a reference now for the first question.

Comment: Oh sorry!!! It was already there..

Comment: The result I used can be found in the book "Measure and probability" by Billingsley. I have the third edition and in this edition it's on p268, theorem 20.5.

Comment: Thank you!!! Just one last thing: so, by the iff result, is it enough to prove that there are **at least** two subsequences of $X_nY_n$ converging a.s.? How can I be sure that going on further all the subsequences converge as well?

Comment: Prove that if $X_n \to X$ a.s. then $X_{n_k} \to X$ a.s. as well (this is trivial to prove, just give it 30 sec thought).

Comment: Yeah, done...trivial, sorry. Thank you for your patience