# $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} Y \implies X_n+Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X+Y$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, statistical-inference

I want to know if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are random variables and $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ and $Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} Y$, we also have

$$X_n+Y_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X+Y$$

I think that's true as well because $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ mean pointwise convergence, that is convergence in the real numbers at every point.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But for a proof you have to use the fact union of two sets of probability $0$ has probability $0$.

Comment: You have the right idea, but you need to deal with the null sets...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you know where I can find this proof? I've already tried, I couldn't find it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932445/two-random-variable-converge-almost-surely-does-the-product-of-this-two-random-v